# L'Hospital and Lebesgue dominated convergence

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, limits

I have $f:\Omega\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded Carathéodory function, $F(x,s)=\int_0^s f(x,t) dt$ and $f$ satisfy this condition $\lim_{s\rightarrow+\infty} f(x,s)=f^{+\infty}(x)$

My  question is: why $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega}\frac{F(x,u_n)}{||u_n||^p}\rightarrow 0$ where $(u_n)$ is a sequence of function from $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega),$ and $||u_n||\rightarrow+\infty$? where $p>1$

I think we must use L'Hospital and Lebesgue dominated convergence but how $F $or $f$ can be dominated by a function $L^1$ ?

Thank you

Comment: Which norm $\Vert u_n \Vert$ are we talking about? The $W^{1,p}$ norm? Also, is $\Omega$ bounded/of finite measure?

Comment: Yes the $W^{1,p}_0$ norm  et $\Omega$ is an open bounded set from $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @PhoemueX have you an idea please ?

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded, you should be able to prove $|F(x,s)| \leq C \cdot |s|$ for all $x,s$. This means that your integral can be estimated by $C \int_\Omega |u_n|/\Vert u_n \Vert^p$. In the case $p>1$, this should give the claim. For $p=1$, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: f is not bounded it is by the mean that f sends bounded sets to bounded sets

Comment: Are you sure about that? Also, I think the claim is false in general, at least for $p=1$. To see this, take $f(x, t) = 1$ for $t \geq 0$ and $f(x,t) = -1$ for $t < 0$. Then $F(x,s) = |s|$ for all $x,s$ and your integral becomes $\int |u_n|/\Vert u_n \Vert^p$. If you now take $u_n = n \cdot v_0$ for some fixed $v_0 \neq 0$, then your integral is constant (and not $0$).

Comment: No $p>1$, that's my professor who told me that $f$ send's bounded sets to bounded sets and there are many paper where $f$ is continuous and the statment still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22296/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-phoemuex).